# Return e console.log não funcionam como esperado no Codecademy

Tags: javascript

Estou fazendo curso de Javascript no [`Codecademy`](http://codeacademy.com), fiz a função, ela está retornado o que o exercício pede, mas não passo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Testa escrever o `oi` com letra grande... -> `Oi`. Esse code academy é um rôbot...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O `return` é uma instrução para a função, não tem ligação algum com o `console.log`.

O `console.log` é um metodo que foi "idealizado" faz pouco tempo (quando já existia javascript e navegadores) para depurar os scripts, você não usa ele para "produção" mas sim para desenvolvimento.

O correto seria "retornar" usando `return` e capturar este retorno com `console.log`

O `return` funciona assim

```
function test(){
    return "test";
}

console.log(test());
```

Então o código deveria ser:

```
function nameString(name)
{
     return "Oi, eu sou " + name;
}

console.log(nameString("Allan"));
console.log(nameString("Susie"));
console.log(nameString("Fred"));
```

Note que o código é executado até antes do `return`, mas o que vier depois não é executado:

```
function nameString(name)
{
     alert(1);//Isto será executado
     return "Oi, eu sou " + name;
     alert(2);//Isto NÃO será executado
}
```

Comment: Já tentei usar o return, mas aparece esta mensagem: "Oops, tente outra vez. Parece que voce nao exibiu nada no console! Voce se lembrou de usar console.log() no resultado de passar seu nome para a função nameString()?"

Comment: @AllanSantos você chamou assim `console.log(nameString("Allan"));`?

Comment: Amigo, muito obrigado.

Apenas pra deixar claro, quer dizer que o "return" não retorna pelo console ?

Comment: @AllanSantos Isto o `return` é uma instrução para a função, não tem ligação algum com o `console.log`, o `console.log` é um metodo que foi inventado faz pouco tempo (quando já existia javascript) para depurar os scripts, você não usa ele para "produção" mas sim para desenvolvimento :)

Answer (score 4):

Tens de corrigir 2 coisas:

- a função tem de dar `return`
- a string que retornas tem de começar com letra grande

O code academy é um Robot, tens de fazer como ele quer.

**#1 -** Repara que a tua função devia ter `return` em vez de `console.log`. O que se pretende é que a função retorne e que depois faças `console.log` da invocação da função (do seu retorno).

O que se pretende é `return "Oi, eu sou" + " " + name;` e não `console.log("Oi, eu sou" + " " + name);`

Depois podes fazer `console.log(nameString('Sergio'));` ou assim var retorno = nameString('Sergio'); console.log(retorno );`

**#2 -** Repara que `oi` e `Oi` são *strings* diferentes. tens de começar com letra grande.

O código como deve ser:

```
var nameString = function (name) {
    return "Oi, eu sou" + " " + name;
};
console.log(nameString('Sergio'));
```